# Automatically load Blackmagic ATEM preset on launch?

Tags: software

How can I load setting from xml file in ATEM television studio automatically on launch?  For example, I may need to launch it in one mode and have one set of presets and click another icon to load it with a different set.

This can be done manually using the "Restore" button in the file menu, but I need it to be done automatically. I have one idea to parse xml with setting and set all parameters one by one, but maybe there is a way to do this automatically.

Comment: I need to load these settings automatically at the start of my program without user intervention

Comment: thanks, that's what I was looking for.  I have made an attempt to make the question easier to understand and incorporated what you mentioned about needing it without user intervention.  Feel free to edit the question further if I misunderstood what your meaning was.

Comment: From StackOverflow sent to here, in principle, the question can be deleted or closed, it is no longer necessary.

Comment: If SO didn't want it, we can let it hang here.  It's not a whole lot more technical than helping someone with FFMPEG command lines and we do that quite a bit.

Comment: Since the ATEM Software Control communicates via UDP, it would be possible to create a script (that you run before starting the program) that would send the given XMLs via Ethernet. Of course this needs to be developed which might be too much of a hassle, but they do have a [nice SDK](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/developer/product/atem).